# How to add or remove an item from a CollectionViewSource?

Tags: wpf, list, binding, collectionviewsource

I want to bind a datagrid.itemsource to a List with anonymous type,so i bind it to a collectionViewSource,but i need to add or remove an item to the list,but i don't know how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CollectionView` and `CollectionViewSource` are, as their name suggest, only **views**. You can only manipulate the original collection. You should use an `ObservableCollection` if you want the changes to be automatically reflected in your UI.

I would advise against using anonymous types for data binding. But if you must - they implement the Equals method, so you should be able to remove items using new items with equal properties or using the item's index.

Comment: ObservableCollection need a type!what should i set for that when i don't know the type?!