# How to add new item to CollectionViewSource?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add or remove an item from a CollectionViewSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823341/how-to-add-or-remove-an-item-from-a-collectionviewsource)

I have a datagrid that is bound to a CollectionViewSource . how can I add newItem to this source using code ?

Answer (score 1):

I Just read the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx).  It says

> You should not create objects of this class in your code. To create a
>   collection view for a collection that only implements IEnumerable,
>   create a CollectionViewSource object, add your collection to the
>   Source property, and get the collection view from the View property.

So, I guess you should not be adding any items to a CollectionViewSource.  Instead you should add items to the wrapping object.

Why do you need to do this anyway, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok . thanks . Source property of CollectionViewSource has bound to objectResult<T> ( I am using entity framework . I executed ObjectQuery<T>.Execute() and bound the result to CollectionViewSource.Source . now how can I Add new item to my source